# поочередное раскрытие/скрытие блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

делаю самописный спойлер вкладки которого имеют связь.

нужен код который будет при клике на блок раскрывать его, а открытый закрывать, и если с этим проблем нет, то как обработать нажатие на уже активный элемент я придумать не могу. нормально закрывается 1 раз, но при следующем открытии класс активности уже не вешается.

вот код самого слайдера:

```
<div class="spoiler">
    <div class="item"><div class="item-title">№201</div>
        <div class="detail">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-title">№202</div>
        <div class="detail">ipsum dolor</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><div class="item-title">№203</div>
        <div class="detail">dolor sit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

из классов все понятно, вот js:

```
$('.spoiler .detail').hide();
$('.spoiler .item-title').click(function(){

    a=0;
    $('.item.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");

    if(typeof $prev != "undefined"){
        if($previ != $(this)[0]){
            $prev.slideUp();
        }else{
            a=1;
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    }
    if(a==1){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }else{
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }

    $prev =  $(this).next();
    $previ =  $(this)[0];
});
```

пробовал и сначала закрывать все блоки, а после работать с нажатым, и запоминать нажатый блок для работы с ним при следующем нажатии, но эту проблему как победить я не знаю, все работает кроме обработки нажатия по одному и тому же блоку(только с классом активности проблема, который меняет стиль, сам блок разворачивается как надо)

Comment: зачем что-то запоминать, если ты вешаешь класс активности на блок? Дак ты и проверяй, если есть класс у элемента по которому кликнули, просто его свернуть, если нет, то свернуть все остальные, а этот развернуть. Вот и вся логика

Comment: даже стыдно стало, ведь были мысли что с активом надо что то делать. надо больше спать. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $spoiler = $('.spoiler');
    var $items = $spoiler.find('.item');

    $spoiler.on('click', '.item-title', function() {
      var $item = $(this).parent();
      var is_active = $item.hasClass('active');

      $items.removeClass('active');

      if (is_active) {
        return;
      }

      $item.addClass('active');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.spoiler .item .detail {
  display: none;
}
.spoiler .item.active .detail {
  display: block;
}
/** Немножко стилей для понятности **/

.spoiler .item .item-title {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.spoiler .item .item-title:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler">
  <div class="item active">
    <div class="item-title">Item №1</div>
    <div class="detail">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-title">Item №2</div>
    <div class="detail">To make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
      and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-title">Item №3</div>
    <div class="detail">Sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Для справки:

> Вам может показаться, что объявление переменных с var и без него всегда приводят к одинаковому результату, но это действительно так только, когда когда объявление происходит в глобальном контексте (т.е. за пределами всех функций).
>
> Если же объявление происходит в локальном контексте (т.е. в теле какой-либо функции) объявление с var создает локальную переменную (т.е. переменную, которая будет доступна только в теле данной функции и после выполнения функции будет уничтожена), объявление без var создает глобальную переменную (т.е. переменную, которая будет доступна другим функциям внутри данного скрипта).
>
> **Чтобы избежать ошибок в коде рекомендуем стараться всегда определять переменные с var.**